# Penalty/Fine by Traffic cop for blocking rear window glass pane

Tags: car, window

[Rear window car](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/rear+window+car)

Will there be a fine by the traffic cop if he finds the back seat of the car mirror glass
blocked by the owner with a bed cover?

I.e. The driver cannot see the back while taking
a reverse as the back seat mirror is blocked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about motor vehicle maintenance and repair, and hence off-topic.

Comment: Legal questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends where you are in the world.  Some legal locations dictate the maximum amount of "tint" a window might have, and driving with an unsafe vehicle may result in action when it is noticed.

Your vehicle may fail its periodic inspection, if your nation requires them.  At that point it cannot be driven on the road except under certain circumstances.

Conversely, consider that trucks may not have any rear window - some of them rely solely on mirrors and driver's skill in manoevering.   Modern trucks have backup cameras, a poor substitute for direct visibility.

If you're the driver, you need to make safe decisions for you and for everyone else on the road, and near your vehicle.     Be a good road user.